# Matching linux paths in sed

Tags: bash, sed

I'm bit confused with sed right now.
I have a bash script there is a variable:

```
_file="/var/log/messages"
```

and lets say we have file containing:

```
/var/log/messages
 /var/log/messages
 random  /var/log/messages
random  /var/log/messages
/var/log/messages random
  /var/log/messages random
 random  /var/log/messages/random
```

I need to match and remove only "/var/log/messages" and "/var/log/messages[[:space:]]"

So the output should be:

```
 random  
random  
random
  random
 random  /var/log/messages/random
```

This does not work:

```
sed -e "s@"$_file"@@" test_file #matches also /var/log/messages/random
sed -e "s@"$_file[[:space:]]"@@" test_file # Does not match end of line occurrences
```

Comment: `"s@$_file[[:space:]]@@"`? Why close `"`?

Comment: `sed -E "s@$_file([[:space:]]|$)@@" test_file `

Comment: @KamilCuk - seems like I pasted it wrong

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew holly cow you just made my day it was the -E not -e I used ! daaaamn I sped so much time figuring this out :D

Answer (score 1):

Then match end of line or `[[:space:]]`. I like single quotes and use double qoutes only for variables.

```
sed -e 's@'"$_file"'[[:space:]]@@' -e 's@'"$_file"'$@@'
```

or

```
sed 's@'"$_file"'\([[:space:]]\|$\)@@'
```